# How to specify where to install RVM on mac OS X?

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rvm, homebrew

I am trying to install RVM after having installed Homebrew and the XCode command line tools, which tested out fine.

My problem is because I used an OWC internal SSD + internal HD OS X (10.7) install as in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ou-heXnkPP4). This means that OS X is installed on my internal SSD whilst the ~/user is on the internal HD drive.

When I try installing with:

```
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:~ rkostucki$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11745  100 11745    0     0   8475      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  8475
mkdir: /rkostucki.rvm: Permission denied
Rubens-MacBook-Pro:~ rkostucki$
```

What happens is that RVM is trying to install into the SSD `users` rather than on the HD, where Ruby, Homebrew and all of my other files are except for the OS.  I know it's a weird set-up.

How can I specifically tell RVM to install in the right location?

I tried deleting RVM. I tried deleting `/rkostucki.rvm` and let it recreate. I went into my SSD/user to remove manually /rkostucki.rvm

Comment: I think you need to use `sudo` for the install. But you shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: `sudo` won't help, it will only make matters worse.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that RVM (and also compilation tool-chain) has very limited support for paths with spaces, it looks like the instructions are not complete:

```
sudo mkdir /$USER.rvm
sudo chown $USER: /$USER.rvm
sudo ln -s "$HOME/.rvm/" /$USER.rvm
echo "export rvm_path=/$USER.rvm" >> "$HOME/.rvmrc"
```

That should do the trick - please open a [ticket for RVM](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues) so it can be fixed for everybody.

Comment: Thanks @mpapis That somehow solved the problem as in the installation went through BUT it installed on the SSD and NOT on the HDD

Comment: is there in your system a path to HDD that does not contain spaces and is not a link to the one with spaces?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by 'contain spaces'?

Comment: `Rubens-MacBook-Pro:~ rkostucki$ ls -ld /Volumes/
drwxrwxrwt@ 7 root  admin  238 14 Mar 10:22 /Volumes/`

Comment: if you want to see how my computer is set up, here s a link to 4 screenshots that will help: http://we.tl/2y9WQTA1A2

Comment: you missed the `*` on the end => `ls -ld /Volumes/*`

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x+  2 rkostucki  admin    68 14 Mar 13:29 /Volumes/Macintosh
drwxr-xr-x  28 root       wheel  1020  2 Dec 22:14 /Volumes/Macintosh HD
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root       admin     1 30 Jan 19:13 /Volumes/SSD 120GB -> /`

Comment: I had basically a similar issue to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582164/mac-installing-rvm-with-home-directory-on-another-drive?rq=1

Comment: so the issue is that your HDD is available in system as `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` - note that there is a space in the name, this breaks not only RVM but also compilation tool-chain (ex. `make`), if you find a 'space less' path to your HDD that is not a link to the one with spaces then you can chang the tricj to use that path instead of SSD drive.

Comment: OK ... sounds tricky. Got a new MBP Retina, fresh, and still with that it took me a while installing RVM. Why is it so complicated? Anyways ... thanks a lot. I might end up re installing the machine!

Comment: it's complicated because of spaces, even if RVM worked fine with spaces there are still issues with make and spaces, not sure if they are make problems or just ruby

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the `.rvm` folder to the drive you want it on, then create a soft-link from there to the original location using:

```
ln -s real_location pretend_location
```

RVM expects a certain set of known locations, and you are messing with its mind. That isn't a good thing to do with tools like RVM as they can easily out-stubborn you. The soft-link might fool it long enough for you to get some work done.

If that doesn't work, try using rbenv. I have been using it lately. RVM is powerful but I didn't need all that. rbenv isn't as capable, nor is it as complicated, and, as a result, I find it less likely to get confused.

Comment: Thanks @TheTinMan - it's all messy so I've decided to redo a full install of ruby, gems, rvm from scratch. what do you recommend is the best way to do it knowing the weird set up I have in terms of SSD + HDD internal, where the OS is on the SSD and the rest (home folder) is on the HDD. if you want, you can find a screenshot of the setup on http://we.tl/2y9WQTA1A2